# Where can I find this in Sefer HaRokeach

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, megillat-esther

I am trying to located "pirush Harokeach" on Meggilat Esther, but I'm having a very hard time finding it.

Specifically i am looking for his pirush on Esther 3:6 regarding Haman being a sorcerer.

(Attached is a photo of only *some* of the times the Rokeach is cited, yet i am having trouble finding it.)

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/40224

Comment: @Avrah i dont think that is it, since it is very short and at the end of each explanation is cites an alternative source.

Comment: @TheT Why are those reasons this can't be it?

Comment: It seems to me in that sefer its only an abbreviated version of what i am looking for, additionally it does not have the specific explanation which i am looking for. i will add that to my original question.

Comment: the HB sefer appears to be a compilation/likkut of material the Tokrach wrote in various places plus things that were written in his name.  @TheTargum - do you know for a fact that ר' אלעזר מגרמייזא wrote an original sefer directly on Megillas Esther?

Comment: @EraserX i will add a photo of the sefer i am learning which cites "HaRokeach" many times, and i have been having much trouble following up on those citations. Being that the sefer and the context is all regarding megilas esther, and the citations seem to match the perek and pasuk in the megillah in which it would make sense to be quoting on.

Comment: What is the name of the sefer you are using? Quite possible that the mechaber is quoting the likkut (published 1959) found on HB mentioned above.

Comment: @EraserX the sefer is called "Pirsumei Nissa". I went through the likut and could not find what was cited, additionally, the likkut does not list the pesukim as the cited source seems to include.

Comment: Who is the author of "Pirsumei Nissa" and what year was it published?

Comment: Tzvi Hirsch Weiss, from WIlliamsburg, its probably not older than 35 years

Comment: The 2nd page of that here https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/169908/p/2/t/1685912851285/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c lists a 718 phone # for the mechaber in the USA.  If you are the investigative type you can try calling.

Comment: @EraserX thank you

Comment: https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3732433-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%97-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%A8

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank You! Do you how \ where i can accesses it online?